# AngularJS: Can't Recognize My Controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

New to coding and Angular, so my understanding of the basics may be at fault here.

Initially my app was fine, but when I tried to build routing into it I ran into some errors. I think I was too ambitious at first and tried to make separate controller files for functionality that I hadn't even built yet (novice mistake). Now, I can't seem to get a basic page (homepage.html) to display what's being entered into a text box. It only shows {{inputs}}, which I believe means that it's not connecting to the controller. I think this is also the case because none of my CSS is loading (the link to the CSS is in index.html).

Here are my JSLint errors:

**1 'angular was used before it was defined' var app = angular.module ('myApp', ['ngRoute']);**

4 Missing 'use strict' statement. $routeprovider.

25 Missing 'use strict' statement. $scope.inputArry=[];
. More 'use strict' messages.

48 Don't make functions within a loop --> will be changing this soon.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>

<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--<script src="js/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script> -->

<div class="header">
    <header>Nick's Test</header>
    <nav>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/about">About</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div ng-view>
    <!-- HELLO WORLD -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**homepage.html** (a page that displays text entered into a textbox)

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<div id="section" style="overflow:auto">
    <ul class="normal">
    <li ng-repeat="inputs in inputArray track by $index"> {{inputs}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <form ng-submit="addInput(stuffToShow)">
        Input:
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="stuffToShow"/>
        <br />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <button ng-click="clear()">Clear All</button>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: "partials/login.html",
            controller: "LoginController"
        })
        .when('/homepage', {
            templateUrl: "partials/homepage.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: "partials/about.html"
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: "partials/contact.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "partials/login.html"
        });
});

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputArray = [];
    $scope.stuffToShow = "";

    $scope.addInput = function(x) {
        $scope.inputArray.push(x);
        $scope.stuffToShow ="";
    };

    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.inputArray = [];
    };
});

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope) {
    $scope.userName = "Nick";
    $scope.password = "123456";
    $scope.verification = true;

    do{
        $scope.userNameCheck = function (name) {
            if (name !== $scope.userName)
                $scope.verification = false;
        };
        $scope.passwordCheck = function (pass) {
            if (pass !== $scope.password)
                $scope.verification = false;
        }
    }while(!$scope.verification);
});
```

**Note**: the LoginController is not finished and the code inside is mostly gibberish.

Comment: `It only shows {{inputs}}` : open the js console, and read what angularjs tells you. You may have a link to click to get details.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention the error that JSLint has been giving me. It says: "angular was used before it was defined. var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);"

I had this error when I first made this app, and fixed it by putting the CDN script above my app.js script. But now I can't seem to find out why the error is happening. I have moved around the order of all the scripts to no avail.

Comment: You can also type `'use strict';` at the top of all your JS files, in order to have more detailed info in console log and to validate your JS code with a more though error / warning checker. It would also remove your erros/warning about use strict issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be like this

mainController.js:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.inputArray = [];
    $scope.stuffToShow = "";

    $scope.addInput = function () {
        $scope.inputArray.push($scope.stuffToShow);
        $scope.stuffToShow = "";
    };

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.inputArray = [];
    };
}]);
```

loginController.js:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.userName = "Nick";
    $scope.password = "123456";
    $scope.verification = true;

    do {
        $scope.userNameCheck = function (name) {
            if (name !== $scope.userName)
                $scope.verification = false;
        };
        $scope.passwordCheck = function (pass) {
            if (pass !== $scope.password)
                $scope.verification = false;
        };
    } while (!$scope.verification);
}]);
```

index.html: 
EDITED!!!

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <!--ADD # FOR ng-route -->
        <a href="#/">Home</a>
        <a href="#/about">About</a>
        <a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#/homepage">Homepage</a>
    </nav>
    <div ng-view>
        <!--HELLO WORD! -->
    </div>
    <!--YOUR JS FILES -->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--I RECOMMEND YOU DOWNLOAD IT -->
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/loginController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/mainController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

EDIT!!

homepage.html

```
<div id="section" style="overflow:auto">
<ul class="normal">
    <li ng-repeat="inputs in inputArray track by $index">{{inputs}}</li>
</ul>
```

```
<div id="footer">
<form>        
    <label>Input:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="stuffToShow"/>
    <br />
    <button ng-click="addInput()">Submit</button>                          
</form>
<button ng-click="clear()">Clear All</button>
```

and finally modify your app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: "views/login.html",
            controller: "loginController" //change the name of the controller
        })
        .when('/homepage', {
            templateUrl: "views/homepage.html",
            controller: "mainController" //change the name of the 
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: "views/about.html"
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: "views/contact.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "views/login.html"
        });
```

});

Comment: Added the angular file and changed the structure of my controllers' arguments, but the errors are all still the same.

Comment: i edited my answer, please see if works fine for you

Answer (score 0):

Basically your scripts are fine, you just need to change a couple of small details.

I have made a fiddle that shows your code working, https://jsfiddle.net/j752hdnp/

Your `<a>`s need to have `#` at the beginning of the url, eg `<a href="#/">Home</a>`

And your `otherwise` needs to refer to one of your urls, not the template file, so change it to be

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/login"
});
```

Last thing, if your loading angular from CDN, you might as well load ngRoute from the CDN as well.

Comment: The index.html page has never had any problems. Rather, it's the homepage.html that I'm trying to fix. If you load it, you can see that it displays {{inputs}} rather than what's being submitted into the text box. I have however, added the `#` and changed the `otherwise`

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a resolution to my problem. It turns out that because I wasn't hosting files on a server, Chrome was giving me errors, particularly

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/**/partials/homepage.html.
```

and

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: partials/homepage.html (HTTP status: -1 )
```

I fixed this by installing node.js and setting up my own file server, and voila! The templates are loading without a problem.